# "TypeError: Failed to fetch" in a POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, fetch-api

I am working on a JavaScript and Node.js project, and my POST requests keep rising "TypeError: Failed to fetch"; however, my GET requests work well. And my POST requests cannot even been finished. I checked the 'Network' tab, and the timing tab within it shows the request is stalled and not finished.

I also added CORS headers in server.js, which is not working. And I saw other post about it said adding 'event.preventDefault()', and this doesn't work for me either as I added it at first.

Below are the codes of fetching:

```
async function handleFormSubmit(postData) {
            // Send a POST request to your API endpoint
            await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/submit", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(postData),
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log("POST Response:", data);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error("POST Error:", error);
            });
        }
        postForm.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const formData = new FormData(postForm);
            const postData = {
                model_id: formData.get("model_id"),
                prompt: formData.get("prompt"),
                bad_response: formData.get("bad_response"),
            };
            handleFormSubmit(postData);
        });
```

**----server.js----**

```
const modelRoutes = require('./src/routes/modelRoutes');

app.use(cors());
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000'); // Replace '*' with your allowed origin
    res.header(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
    );
    next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '10mb', extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));

app.use(express.json());
app.use('/api', modelRoutes);
```

**----modelRoutes.js----**

`router.post('/submit', hallucinationController.submitHallucination);`

**----controller----**

```
const submitHallucination = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { model_id, prompt, bad_response } = req.body;
        // Use the public key to verify the request (optional).
        console.log('controller:', prompt); //Here cannot reach for now
        const mId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(model_id);

        const newSave = {
            model_id: mId,
            prompt: prompt,
            bad_response: bad_response,
            p_tuned: false,
        };

        // Save the hallucination data to your database (e.g., HALLUCINATION table).
        const hallucination = new Hallucination(newSave);
        const saved = await hallucination.save();
        // Return a success message.
        Utilities.apiResponse(
            res,
            200,
            'Hallucination submitted successfully!',
            {},
        );
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error:', error);
        Utilities.apiResponse(res, 500, error);
    }
};
```

Does anyone know what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your `postForm.addEventListener` you have this line:

```js
handleFormSubmit(postData);
```

This means you are passing the `postData` object to the `handleFormSubmit` function. I am going to assume you have checked to make sure all of your data is contained in `postData` with a `console.log(postData)` just before you call `handleFormSubmit(postData);`.

Now for some reason you never send the `postData` object because in the body of your `post` request you are sending an empty object:

```js
body: JSON.stringify({}),
```

You need to send the `postData` in the body like so:

```js
body: JSON.stringify(postData),
```

Your routing looks fine. The `http://localhost:3000/api/submit` will be caught by `app.use('/api', modelRoutes);` which will then route to the `router.post('/submit',)` to invoke your `hallucinationController.submitHallucination`function.

Comment: Oh, my bad. That was a debugging empty object, have corrected it now. If I include postData in the body, the payload actually can catch the body's data, but for some reasons I don't know it doesn't complete the request and catches an error.

Comment: @Claire what is the exact error that is returned?

Comment: Here is the full error message: Error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at handleFormSubmit (5d68hx-3000.csb.app/:154:19)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (5d68hx-3000.csb.app/:178:4)
console.<computed> @ index.js:9
p @ preview-protocol.js:57
(anonymous) @ 5d68hx-3000.csb.app/:168
handleFormSubmit @ 5d68hx-3000.csb.app/:155

Comment: Also I don't get any backend debug result as all my 'console.log' debugging statements are not printed. It seems that it doesn't jump into the controller.

Comment: @Claire Is the document being saved? i.e. does this work `const saved = await hallucination.save();` ? Your custom code `Utilities.apiResponse` looks highly suspicious. The `res` object already comes with numerous methods for returning a response so you don't have to reinvent the wheel so to speak.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that your fetch options include the correct method ("POST") and headers. In your handleFormSubmit function, you are setting headers and the body but not including the actual data:

```
body: JSON.stringify(postData),
```

Try This Code For Your handleFormSubmit Function --->

```
async function handleFormSubmit(postData) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/hallucination", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(postData),
    });

    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("POST Response:", data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("POST Error:", error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for that, I have corrected the empty body. That was not my intended code. I checked the Network, and the payload actually can get the body's data, but the request can't be completed and get an error.